# File.Exists function in C# throwing "File not found" exception

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (File.Exists(Path +"\\connect"))
{
    Login log = new Login();
    MainClass.showWindow(log,this);
}
else 
{
    Settings set = new Settings();`MainClass.showWindow(set,this);
}
```

My path has no file with name "connect" but the `else` part is not executed when I run the program. The "file not found" exception thrown. Settings window is not shown when I run the program it says file not found.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, there is a weird back tick ` in your else clause

Comment: Weird... The code works fine here. you probably don't have any hidden files with the name "connect", right?

Comment: I don't recomment using Path as a variable name since it's a class name (in the namespace System.IO, same namespace than File). maybe try this instead:`string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path,"connect"))){...}`

Comment: are you running program through Visual Studio ?  What is value of path variable ?  I have executed the similar code which checks non existing file, it is not throwing any exception.

Comment: Why do you believe it is not hitting the else?  A breakpoint?

Comment: Yeah i dont have the file name connect thats y i am telling the else part should be executed by showing up a setting window but only if part works.